# HTTP Status 500 - java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbc, tomcat7

I wrote a java servlet program but when i run it, It was showing the error HTTP Status 500 - java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date I searched how to any other way for inserting date type to the database but i didn't got possible way to do so.My code is :

```
   package skypark;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
      import java.sql.*;
      import java.sql.Date;
  public class Registration extends HttpServlet
 {
  /**
   * 
   */
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     public static Connection prepareConnection()throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
{
String dcn="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@JamesPJ-PC:1521:skypark";
String usname="system";
String pass="tiger";
Class.forName(dcn);
return DriverManager.getConnection(url,usname,pass);
  }
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException,IOException
 {
resp.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();
try
{
String phone1,dofb,date1,month,year,uname,fname,lname,address,city,state,country,pin,email,password,gender,lang,qual,relegion,privacy,hobbies,fav;

uname=req.getParameter("uname");
fname=req.getParameter("fname");
lname=req.getParameter("lname");
date1=req.getParameter("date");
month=req.getParameter("month");
year=req.getParameter("year");
address=req.getParameter("address");
city=req.getParameter("city");
state=req.getParameter("state");
country=req.getParameter("country");
pin=req.getParameter("pin");
email=req.getParameter("email");
password=req.getParameter("password");
gender=req.getParameter("gender");
phone1=req.getParameter("phone");
lang="";
qual="";
relegion="";
privacy="";
hobbies="";
fav="";
dofb=date1 +"-"+ month +"-" + year;
int phone=Integer.parseInt(phone1);
DateFormat formatter ; 
java.util.Date dob ; 
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
dob = formatter.parse(dofb); 

Connection con=prepareConnection();
String Query="Insert into regdetails values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(Query);
ps.setString(1,uname);
ps.setString(2,fname);
ps.setString(3,lname);
ps.setDate(4,(Date) dob);
ps.setString(5,address);
ps.setString(6,city);
ps.setString(7,state);
ps.setString(8,country);
ps.setString(9,pin);
ps.setString(10,lang);
ps.setString(11,qual);
ps.setString(12,relegion);
ps.setString(13,privacy);
ps.setString(14,hobbies);
ps.setString(15,fav);
ps.setString(16,gender);

int c=ps.executeUpdate();

String query="insert into passmanager values(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(query);

ps1.setString(1,uname);
ps1.setString(2,password);
ps1.setString(3,email);
ps1.setInt(4,phone);

int i=ps1.executeUpdate();

if(c==1||c==Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO && i==1||i==Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO)
{
    out.println("<html><head><title>Login</title></head><body>");
    out.println("<center><h2>Skypark.com</h2>");
    out.println("<table border=0><tr>");
    out.println("<td>UserName/E-Mail</td>");
    out.println("<form action=login method=post");
    out.println("<td><input type=text name=uname></td>");
    out.println("</tr><tr><td>Password</td>");
    out.println("<td><input type=password name=pass></td></tr></table>");
    out.println("<input type=submit value=Login>");
    out.println("</form></body></html>");
}
else
{
    out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title></head><body>");
    out.println("<center><b>Given details are incorrect</b>");
    out.println(" Please try again</center></body></html>");
    RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("registration.html");
    rd.include(req,resp);
    return;
  }
 }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
  out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title><body>");
  out.println("<b><i>Class not found "+ cnfe +"</i></b>");
  out.println("</body></html>");
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
     out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title><body>");
      out.println("<b><i>Unable to process try after some time Sql error</i></b>");
      out.println("</body></html>");
} catch (ParseException e) {
     out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title><body>");
      out.println("<b><i>Unable to process Parseint exc " + e +"</i></b>");
      out.println("</body></html>");
}
 /* catch(Exception e)
 {
   out.println("<html><head><title>Error!</title><body>");
  out.println("<b><i>Unable to process try after some time</i></b>");
  out.println("</body></html>");
  RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("registration.html");
  rd.include(req,resp);
  return;
}*/
out.flush();
out.close();
}
}
```

The error was

```
 HTTP Status 500 - java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
type Exception report
message java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
skypark.Registration.doPost(Registration.java:67)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.33logs.
```

Please any one help me for resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PreparedStatement.setDate()` method expects a `java.sql.Date` as argument. You have a `java.util.Date` which is not a `java.sql.Date`, and you're trying to cast it to a `java.sql.Date`. That can't work. Casting doesn't change the type of an object.

To create a `java.sql.Date` from a `java.util.Date`, use

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting to `java.sql.Date` you should create a `java.sql.Date object`

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Then use the `sqlDate` in `ps.setDate`